# Internal paddig of WPF EditableTextBlock not working

Tags: wpf, padding, textblock

I have the following in my XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueParserTemplate">
        <v:EditableTextBlock x:Name ="scalarEditorTextBox" Margin="17,3,0,0" Width="134" Height="29" 
                 FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="13"
                 Visibility="{Binding IsValueEditorVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                 Text="{Binding Path=DisplayValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay,
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                 ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                 Focusable="True"
                 TextAlignment="{Binding PxValueDefinition,Converter={StaticResource aignmentConverter}}"
                 ReadOnly="{Binding IsOutput, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vo:OutputTreeView}}}"
                 ScalarDataType="{Binding Path=PxValueDefinition}"
                 TextBlockBackgroundColor="{StaticResource ScalarBackground}"
                 TextBoxBackgroundColor="{StaticResource ScalarBackground}"
                 Background="{StaticResource ScalarBackground}"
                 BorderBrush ="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"/> 
    </DataTemplate>
```

And I want to have internal padding for the text of the TextBlock.
I tried adding:

```
padding="5,5,5,5" -> no success
padding="50"      -> no success
```

Nothing works. See:

[image: Result]

Do you have any idea how can I have what I want?

Thank you.

---

Edit:
Ahh...I guess I have to add padding into the EditableTextBlock!
The EditableTextBlock XAML:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="134"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>            
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_GridContainer" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TbDisplayText" Visibility="Visible" 
                                       Background="{Binding TextBlockBackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" 
                                       Foreground="{Binding TextBlockForegroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" 
                                       Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,3,0"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TbEditText" 
                                     Visibility="Hidden" 
                                     Background="{Binding TextBoxBackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" 
                                     Foreground="{Binding TextBoxForegroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" 
                                     Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                     BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" 
                            Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ShowFocusVisual" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I guess your EditableTextBlock is an usercontrol, right? Can you post the xaml of it?

Comment: Edited the question, and added the EditableTextBlock XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the margin of the TextBlock and TextBox in your template to be binding to the Padding property of their parent:

```
    <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid x:Name="PART_GridContainer" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TbDisplayText" Visibility="Visible"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                   Background="{Binding TextBlockBackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" 
                                   Foreground="{Binding TextBlockForegroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" 
                                   Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,3,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TbEditText" 
                                 Visibility="Hidden" 
                                 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                 Background="{Binding TextBoxBackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" 
                                 Foreground="{Binding TextBoxForegroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}}" 
                                 Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:EditableTextBlock}}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                 BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```